# Android MediaPlayer On Stop Event, or similar, exists?

Tags: android, events, callback, media-player

I have several activities which use several audio features. For that, I have a MediaPlayer in a singleton java class, so the activities interact with that class and just exist on the media player.

One of the features is to stop automatically the media player after X minutes. So I created a timer in the singleton class and stops perfectly the radio streaming. the problem is that there is no feedback or callback to the running activity. There is a play/stop button wich has to change the image and I do not know how can I capture that onStop event  or whatever....or can be called from a single java class the current activity class running, so I could call a function of the activity in order to change the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a broadcast receiver for this.

From your singlton class which does the stopping, when your timer stops the music, call this method:

```
public void broadcastMusicPaused(View v){
    Intent broadcast = new Intent();
    broadcast.setAction("MUSIC_STOPPED");
    sendBroadcast(broadcast);
}
```

Then, from your controlling activity, set up your receiver like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        displayMusicStopped();       //switches images
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("MUSIC_STOPPED");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that sounds really good, if i have time i will try, but i have to solve some big problems in just these days :(
But that code sounds like what i was expecting, but i did the trick other way

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks jameo for his answer, sounds pretty good, but i do not know if i will have time to try, i promise i will if i can this week or next time i have a similar issue.

Finally i did the trick this way:

1 - Create a Interface with Method onStopMediaPlayer(); //For example call MediaPlayerStopInterface

```
public interface MediaPlayerStopInterface {
    /**
     * Called when the player timer ends 
     */
  public void onStopMediaPlayer();
}
```

2 - My activities classes implements the interface switching images.

```
public class PortadaActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayerStopInterface{
    public void onStopMediaPlayer(){
        //Switch images or whatever
    }
}
```

3 - My singletton class has an object of the type of the interface MediaPlayerStopInterface

```
public class AudioControllerClass {   //The Singletton Java Class
    private MediaPlayerStopInterface currentActivity;

    public void setCurrentActivity(MediaPlayerStopInterface mpsi){
    currentActivity=mpsi;
}
}
```

4 - My activities classes in onResume() do a Singlettonclass.setStoppedPlayerInterface(this), so i always have a reference of the running activitie.

```
public class PortadaActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayerStopInterface{
    public void onResume() {
        AudioControllerClass.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setCurrentActivity(this); //In every resume the singletton class knows who was the last one in being active
    }
}
```

5 - when timer execute, as i have the activitie class reference, i just call object_StoppedPlayerInterface.stoppedPlayer();

```
public class AudioControllerClass {   //The Singletton Java Class
    class TimerRadio extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            if(whatever==true){
                currentActivity.onStopMediaPlayer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, i didn't code it, but the callback to onStopMediaplayer in activities must be done with a Handler, if you do not want a "Only UI thread can touch his views" exception :P

It works perfectly :). But i don't know if it is a really bad practice or is not so horrible xD

Anyway thanks Jameo. Yours sound much more elegant :P

Comment: Post a couple of snippets of actual code and I will up your answer!  Sounds like it could help someone else!

Comment: done, thats all the code excepts the handler part...i hope it can be understandable :)
This works great, but probably your solution is more elegant/efficient

Comment: You used a callback interface...It's probably technically less overhead, just more lines of code in multiple places.  Broadcast receivers are really flexible, and powerful, so next time you need to communicate between processes, try it out!